# i am trying to animate two image in which when one clicks on the displayed image it disappears through alpha equals to 0 and the other image appears

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

having a problem understanding the difference between else and if statement in the given code, it's working with else but not working with if statement.

```
public void fade(View view) {

    Log.i("value", "simpson image tapped");


    ImageView homerImage = findViewById(R.id.homer);
    ImageView simpsonImage = findViewById(R.id.simpson);

    if (bartIsShowing) {


        Log.i("value", "simpson image animated to alpha 0");
        simpsonImage.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        homerImage.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);
        bartIsShowing = false;
    }

    else {
        Log.i("value", "homey image animated to alpha 0");
        homerImage.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        simpsonImage.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);

        bartIsShowing = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: "don't understand the difference between if and else"? you mean it always executes the else block and you don't know why?

Comment: I understand why it's executing the else block but I have a problem with if statement, it does not execute with if statement, according to my knowledge it means exactly the same.

Comment: no, it isn't. though the difference is minimal. basically, you can do without the if-else blocks, and end with: bartIsShowing = !bartIsShowing;

Comment: if(!bartIsShowing) {
        Log.i("value", "homey image animated to alpha 0");
        homerImage.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
        simpsonImage.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);

        bartIsShowing = true;

    }

Comment: I was trying the above code and it was not doing anything I also checked the logs in logs I got that bartIsShowing was never getting the boolean value of false.

Comment: your change is incorrect. why would you add that if?

Comment: to execute if bartIsShowing is false block.

Comment: there should not be a false (or else) block.